# Setting maximum tile size in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, tiles

Is it possible to set a maximum tile size that can be generated in GeoServer?

I have a GeoServer instance that is being hit directly by requests for massive, continent spanning tiles that are consuming an enormous amount of resources.

Until I get a better security solution is in place to stop this, I was wondering if there was a way to make GeoServer ignore tile requests over a certain size.

Comment: You can use scale dependent rules (Min/MaxScaleDenominator) https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rules.html so that the continent spanning tiles contain just a simplified shoreline or something else pretty lightweight data.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to set the WMS request limits (which are also used to produce WMTS tiles):
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/configuration.html#request-limits

You might also want to read these resources:

- https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/index.html
- https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/multidim/adv_gsconfig/index.html
- https://speakerdeck.com/simboss/geoserver-in-production (especially the second half of the slides).